# How can I lay a div over every image on the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how can I put a div over every image element on the page using `jQuery`? I want to make it where when you right click on the image, you'll just be right clicking on a div and then it will be harder to save, and people that don't know `HTML` and stuff wont be able to get the image since they wont even know about "View page source" option. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make them all divs and with CSS alone, assign the graphics as background images?  No JS required and you'll have the same end result.

Comment: End result: I, as a user, get frustrated. If I really want the image, I'll get it. If I don't want it that bad I'll never visit the site again :) The CSS approach does not allow specifying an "alt", among other things.

Comment: @Sparky672 Yeah, but then that requires me to re-size the images to fit. (Right now, I just used style="width:;height:;" to make the image smaller) But I'll try that. Thanks.

This is the site: www.americaspoeticsoul.com

Comment: @pst Yes, that's what I do too if I really want the image (I don't know about never visiting the site again though.) The visitors coming to my client's site wont know anything about HTML, CSS, etc. though. They are basic users. So I don't think they'll be able to get the image because the only method they know is to right-click and save.

Also, what you do mean by an "alt"? Do you mean img alt?

Comment: @Nathan:  Yes, that's true but your images should be the correct size regardless.  Using `style=width:Xpx;height:Ypx;` forces the browser to re-size the image and that's not going to be as efficient and simply loading the image at it's native size.

Comment: @pst Yes it does. Just set a title for the div. I'd recommend the CSS approach. Alternatively you can turn off the right click entirely but this is rather more annoying IMO.

Comment: @Sparky672 That's true. I'll just re-size the images in PhotoShop and then re-upload them to the server. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I feel bad since this is obviously a demand from your client but there are so many ways other than right click save that you haven't thought of. You can take a screenshot with Print Screen, you can take a screenshot with one of the thousands of browser addons out there (my favourite: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ehoopddfhgaehhmphfcooacjdpmbjlao), there's desktop applications and of course, you can always take a picture of the monitor.

Comment: @Nathan:  Glad to help... please don't forget to "accept" my answer below.

Comment: @Radu That is also true. But, these people are very basic users. They may not even know how to take screen shots. If you take a picture of the monitor, it will be a very crappy looking image I think. I tried taking a picture of something on my screen with my iPhone and it wasn't as good as just searching Google Images for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop a new DIV on top of the images using absolute positioning:

```
.hider {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and this code:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $('<div/>', {title: this.alt})
        .addClass('hider')
        .css({
            width: this.width, height: this.height,
            left: pos.left, top: pos.top,
        })
        .insertAfter(this);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/KRgnK/ for a working demo

**EDIT** updated to copy the original image's `alt` tag onto the overlay div.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! :) If I could "vote up" this answer I would but sadly I am still 1 reputation! I don't know how to get more than 1 reputation.

Comment: @Nathan you have 6 reputation now...  I upvoted your question.

Answer (score 2):

If blocking the right-click on the image is important, I recommend a simple CSS approach where the image is just the background of a DIV.  You cannot right-click to download these images regardless of any JavaScript.

As mentioned, you'll be missing the `alt` image attribute so proceed accordingly.

The HTML...

```
<div id="myImage"></div>
```

And the CSS...

```
<style>

#myImage {
    background-image: url(theGraphic.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100px;  /* theGraphic.jpg width */
    height: 100px;  /* theGraphic.jpg height */
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this for people that have JavaScript disabled. (using `<noscript></noscript>` tags)

Comment: Can I "accept" 2 answers? There are 2 really helpful answers!

Comment: @Nathan:  No, but in a very short amount of time, you'll have enough reputation to come back and vote up answers.  Your question will remain in your history so you won't forget about it.

Comment: Okay, when I have 15 Reputation, I'll come back and vote up your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, I know you will.

Answer (score 0):

To disable right click entirely, you can use jquery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
 $('body img').wrap('<div />');
```

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/LyPLe/)

Comment: Does not seem to work.  I'm in Safari and I can still right-click and "save image", etc.

Comment: He wants an empty DIV block on top and cover the image, not put the image inside of a DIV.

Comment: try this one http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/LyPLe/1/, but it is the best idea to, it is better to use an watermark :)

Comment: Again, does not work in Safari.  Dismiss the alert box and I still have access to the right-click menu.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/LyPLe/4/, you have a <div> inside , use the css with position to make it on the Image

Comment: Again, still does not work in Safari.  Can still access right-click menu, this time without an alert.  Wrapping it in DIVs is not helping either.  He wants to **cover** the image, not put it inside something.  Three strikes, I'm done.

Comment: I'll just do this:

`<div style="position:relative;">
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
<img src="image.jpg" />
</div>`

Would that work in Safari also?

Comment: @Nathan:  Safari just happens to be what I'm using... I have not tested your code but it seems like it should "cover" the image with an empty DIV.